# Add Rich Snippets Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, open-graph, rich-snippets

I have the following code, which I have appended to the `opengraph/general.phtml` file in Magento 2.

I am hoping this will add the **rich snippet data** required by Google, but I am receiving an error (blank page).

**Existing Code of opengraph/general.phtml**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>

<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName())) ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getImage($block->getProduct(), 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()) ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription())) ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProduct()->getProductUrl()) ?>" />
<?php if ($priceAmount = $block->getProduct()->getFinalPrice()):?>
    <meta property="product:price:amount" content="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $priceAmount ?>"/>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('meta.currency') ?>
<?php endif;?>

<?php /** Rich Snippet Code */ ?>

    <?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_brand = $this->getBrand($_product);
$_sku = $this->getSku($_product); 
?>

<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "https://schema.org/",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeQuote($block->stripTags($_product->getName())); ?>",
        "image": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->stripTags($block->getImage($_product, 'product_base_image')->getImageUrl()); ?>",
        "description": "<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeQuote($block->stripTags($block->getDescription($_product))); ?>",
<?php if (strlen(trim($_brand))): ?>
        "brand": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "name": "<?php echo $block->stripTags($_brand); ?>"
        },
<?php endif; ?>
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "<?php echo $block->getCurrencyCode() ?>",
            "url": "<?php echo $block->stripTags($block->getCurrentUrl($_product)); ?>",
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
            "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
 <?php else : ?>
            "availability": "https://schema.org/OutOfStock",
<?php endif; ?>
            "price": "<?php echo $this->getPrice(); ?>",
            "priceValidUntil": "<?php echo $_product->getSpecialToDate(); ?>"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Can anyone please advise a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure these bits are okay

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_brand = $this->getBrand($_product);
$_sku = $this->getSku($_product);
```

I would have expected something like this

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$_brand = $_product->getBrand();
$_sku = $_product->getSku();
```

But ideally need to see errors in error log

Comment: That was exactly the issue Dominic. Thank you.